# How can I see live previews while editing CSS in a Rails App in Textmate 2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, textmate2

All I want to prevent is having to constantly refresh the page (and subsequently make DB calls on the view) which takes forever.

I would love to be able to just making CSS changes and see it reflected in the document/page/site immediately.

Anyway to do this in Textmate 2 on OS X and Rails 3.2.x?

Comment: you might want to do it in the browser using tools like FireFox/Firebug or Chrome/Developer Tools

Comment: http://livereload.com/

Comment: Hrmm...livereload looks awesome. I wish there was a free equivalent though :(

Comment: If you put livereload as an answer, I will accept it. I tried it, and I love it!

Answer (score 0):

[Livereload.com](http://livereload.com) has solutions for OSX, windows, and linux, the last is free if you dont mind a more than a little extra setup.